why is my curve so blocky?
I followed this tutorial: https://youtu.be/wu_TkcQZqJg?si=ToHyxhPjGI12CqsC
Her curve is somehow much smoother than mine and I have no idea why as I followed the exact steps of her tutorial. I have 4.2.3, she has 3.0.0 (I believe, half of the version number got cut off I the video)


Hello maybe check the resolution of your curve (at the top of the curve panel), if it's not problem please share your file?

It didn't solve it:c thanks for the help!!
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DO9Ax7fyiviTzeHNKr3LeLujhsEz_-po/view?usp=share_link

what kind of curve have you created? You need to create a nurbs, a path or a bezier (Shift A > Curve > ...), I guess this is the nature of your curve that causes the problem here

that didn't work for me unfortunately. I made a path, and a path circle, and then selected the path so I can eyedrop or select the circle as the bevel object but blender didn't find it nor recognized it with the eyedropper

oh ok i get it, under Active Spline, increase the Order U value (I'm not familiar with Path curves)

Under Active Spline, increase the Order U value:

